# error to startActivity(intent), whats going wrong?

Tags: android, url, android-intent, webview, tabs

Below here in code startActivity(intent) gives me an error

Here's my code:

```
public class MyWebViewClient3 extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.facebook.com")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);//this is where it goes wrong
        return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: Whats the error bro..? compile time..? Run time exception..?

Comment: tried "http://" its not working...

Comment: You can't call startActivity from WebViewClient.

Comment: @ngesh:   The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type MyWebViewClient

Comment: @santhosh: yeah i tried this in other examples it works bt not for this, i cnt get it why is this happening...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

WebViewClient  client is not a **context** , so you cannot start Activity from here.. You might want to get Context as a reference and then say

```
context.startActivity(intent);
```

After **vmironov**'s suggestion..

```
@Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.facebook.com")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: you can get a `Context` from a `WebView` passed to `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`

Comment: thnx thts so great of u all its really worked for me... really thnx.. :)