# Remove arguments to match Intent()

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I am trying to make a simple android game, yet I am unable to switch activities. I am getting an error on my Intent() code that says:

> The constructor Intent(MenuView, Class< Game >) is undefined
> 1 quick fix available:
> Remove arguments to match Intent()

I have tried multiple solutions, and taken a lot of time, but so far no fix.
Solutions tried:

-[Android Remove arguments to match "intent()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631998/android-remove-arguments-to-match-intent)
-[Android: Intent asks remove argument & getBaseContext() ask to create its method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30672150/android-intent-asks-remove-argument-getbasecontext-ask-to-create-its-method)
-[StartActivity() red highlighted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266355/startactivity-red-highlighted)
-[error to startActivity(intent), whats going wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516230/error-to-startactivityintent-whats-going-wrong)

```
package com.gregsapps.fallingbird;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Align;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.View;

public class MenuView extends View{
private Context context;

        Paint text;
        Paint red;
        Paint pink;
        Rect playRect;
        boolean usePink = false;
        Rect tempPlayRect;
        //String playText = "PLAY";
        char[] playTextArray;
        int runs = 10;

        public MenuView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            this.context = context;
            this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            tempPlayRect = new Rect();
            playRect = new Rect();
            playTextArray = new char[4];
            playTextArray[0] = 'P';
            playTextArray[1] = 'L';
            playTextArray[2] = 'A';
            playTextArray[3] = 'Y';
            text = new Paint();
            text.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            text.setTextSize(100f);
            red = new Paint();
            red.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
            red.setTextSize(100f);
            pink = new Paint();
            pink.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 69, 0));
            System.out.println("setup");
        }

        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
            if(runs == 10) runOnce(canvas);
            System.out.println("Looping");
            playRect.offsetTo(canvas.getWidth()/2 - playRect.width()/2, canvas.getHeight()/3);
            //System.out.println(playRect.centerX());
            canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(10, 255, 255));
            canvas.drawText("FallingBird", canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/10, text);
            if(usePink) canvas.drawRect(playRect, pink);
            else canvas.drawRect(playRect, red);
            //canvas.drawText("PLAY", canvas.getWidth()/2-(playRect.width()-20)/2, canvas.getHeight()/5, text);
            canvas.drawText("PLAY", canvas.getWidth()/2, (int) (canvas.getHeight()/3 + (tempPlayRect.height()+canvas.getHeight()/20)), text);
            System.out.println(text.measureText("PLAY"));
            runs++;
            usePink = false;
            //if(StaticVarHandler.touch == false){
            //  StaticVarHandler.touchX = -1;
            //  StaticVarHandler.touchY = -1;
            //  System.out.println("not touched!");
            //}
            System.out.println(StaticVarHandler.touch);
            if(playRect.contains(StaticVarHandler.touchX, StaticVarHandler.touchY)){
                //usePink = true;
                context.startActivity(new Intent(this, Game.class));
                //startActivity(i);
            }
            invalidate();
        }

        private void runOnce(Canvas canvas) {
            text.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
            text.setTextSize(canvas.getWidth()/15);
            System.out.println("run once" + text.measureText("PLAY"));
            text.getTextBounds(playTextArray, 0, playTextArray.length, tempPlayRect);
            playRect.set(0, 0, (int) (text.measureText("PLAY")+canvas.getWidth()/20), tempPlayRect.height()+canvas.getWidth()/20);
            //playRect.top += 10;
            //playRect.bottom += 10;
            //playRect.left += 10;
            //playRect.right += 10;
            runs = 0;
        }
}
```

Error location:

```
            System.out.println(StaticVarHandler.touch);
            if(playRect.contains(StaticVarHandler.touchX, StaticVarHandler.touchY)){
                //usePink = true;
                context.startActivity(new Intent(this, Game.class));
                //startActivity(i);
            }
```

Manifest:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Game"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(this, Game.class));
```

to

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Game.class));
```

`this` in the first case refers to the `View` class, but the `Intent` constructor is expecting an `Activity` context.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks for the fast replay! Still have to wait three minutes before I press accept!